# Kivy ScrollView Doesn't work with on_touch_down method

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am trying to use ScrollView in Widget class but it doesn't work when i put a on_touch_down method. What's a problem? How to solve this?

Here is a code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

Window.size = (520, 960)


class GameManager(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width/2, Window.height*3/4))
        root.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(root)

    #When I delete this method everything is fine
    def on_touch_down(self, touch): 
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
             pass


class ScrollViewApp(App):
    game = GameManager()
```

Answer (score 2):

`touch_down` event propagate down the widget tree, first being passed to the root widget and then having each widget pass the touch to its children. The problem is that,  you overwrote `on_touch_down` method and the event isn't propagate, consecuencely your `ScrollView` not respont to this event.

You should only call the `on_touch_downd` method of the parent to allow event propagation:

```
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
             pass

        super(GameManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```